# Does the Skanda Purana accept Rama as the full incarnation of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, rama, avatars, skanda-purana

Consider the following statement by Vyasa in Skanda Purana

> Formerly, at the advent of Treta, the lotus-eyed **Rama, a partial incarnation of Visnu** was born in the Solar race, as a scion of the family of Raghu.
>
> [[Chapter 30(page no 156) - Chapter 2 - Part 9]](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/21994/4/Chapter%202_81-160p.pdf)

Does the same Purana say that Rama is a full incarnation of Vishnu anywhere?

Comment: I  don't know about the classification of slokas in Skanda Purana, hence kept a link with the page number and so on. If someone knows about it, please edit it...

Comment: Are you sure this version of Skanda purana is legit? I have never encountered any purana denoting a partial incarnation that specific. I question the authenticity of this translation.